How to load test data into a Julia DataFrame when the DataFrame is a component of another struct
I have created a type (struct) in Julia.
struct ExampleStruct
    data::DataFrame
end

It has some associated functions/methods which I want to write unit tests for.
Here's an example of a made up test.
function has_names(df)
    return length(names(df)) > 0
end

I'm a bit stuck with two issues.

the type needs a constructor
the test needs a way to initialize the object with some data for testing

Here is the data which I intend to use for testing.
test_data = [
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"],
    ["1", "2", "3"],
    ["1a", "2a" "3a"],
    ["1b", "2b" "3b"],
]

If I were testing a DataFrame directly, I could use the following constructor to initialize it.
example_df = DataFrame(test_data[2:end, :], Symbol.(test_data[1, :]))

But since the DataFrame is contained within the struct ExampleStruct, the ExampleStruct constructor function needs some way to accept data of this type and pass it along to the DataFrame constructor function. (Probably.)
# inner constructor
function ExampleStruct( arg? )
    data(arg) # ?
end

# outer constructor
function ExampleStruct( test_data? )
    ExampleStruct(test_data) # calling the inner constructor here??
end

When not running the unit tests, but running normal code, the data would be loaded from file. There could be multiple possible file formats, one of which would be CSV.
So, in "normal" (not test) code, the constructor of the ExampleStruct should do something like this to initialize data:
# elsewhere, but could be a different file type as well
#using CSV
#csvfile = CSV.File(filename)
# 

data = DataFrame(csvfile)

The "missing piece of the puzzle" here is the constructor function for ExampleStruct. (I think.) Which I can't figure out how to write. (That was probably obvious from the sketched out code I provided for the "inner" and "outer constructors" above.)
I think it needs two methods because it needs to handle two cases.

There is the case of initializing the DataFrame data from some pre-determined data. This is used for testing. In this case I used a Vector{Vector{String}} to store the data, but it could be some other type if something else is easier to work with. (Column names are hard to define when using Vector{Vector{T}}.)
Then there is the case of initializing the DataFrame from some file format. It could be a CSV.File or it might be some other format. I would guess there is a way to express this using an abstract type which is the union of all possible file types. I'm not that knowledgeable about Julia - this is just my feeling for how it might work from reading the documentation.

I hope the question makes sense. I only just started working with Julia so this is all well beyond my knowledge at the moment.
If I were doing this in Python, I might write something like this:
class ExampleStruct:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, list):
            self.data = DataFrame(arg[1:], cols=arg[0])
        else:
            # assume arg is some kind of file object, init from this

The above should be treated as pseudocode. A better design would probably be to use kwargs rather than inspecting the type of arg.

Your question is really about how to encapsulate a structure within another data structure and then access the inner data structure via the outer structure, which is basic to any object capable language. Essentially, you address the DataFrame member you chose to call data in your struct:
struct ExampleStruct
    data::DataFrame
end

with the "." operator, so that if examp is an ExampleStruct, its DataFrame member is accessed as examp.data.
See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Composite-Types. You gave a Python example, and Python classes are similar though they do not generally type struct members in the declarations, and the fact that many Python classes declare their members via use rather than explicitly may have kept you from learning this :(.
So you have for example:
using CSV
using DataFrames

struct ExampleStruct
    data::DataFrame
end

function has_names(df::DataFrame)
    return length(names(df)) > 0
end
has_names(examplestruct::ExampleStruct) = has_names(examplestruct.data)

# here we give a Matrix rather than the vector of vectors you did
test_data = [
    "col1" "col2" "col3";
    "1" "2" "3";
    "1a"  "2a"  "3a";
    "1b" "2b" "3b";
]


example_df = DataFrame(test_data[2:end, :], Symbol.(test_data[1, :]))


function ExampleStruct( data )
    df = DataFrame(data[2:end, :], Symbol.(data[1, :]))
    return ExampleStruct(df)
end
ExampleStruct(csvfilename::AbstractString) = ExampleStruct(DataFrame(CSV.File(csvfilename)))

testexample = ExampleStruct(test_data)

@show testexample has_names(testexample)

which prints
testexample = ExampleStruct(3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ col1    col2    col3
     │ String  String  String
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ 1       2       3
   2 │ 1a      2a      3a
   3 │ 1b      2b      3b)
has_names(testexample) = true

.A note on inner versus outer constructors. Julia structs have a default inner constructor, via a built-in function with function name the name of the struct and arguments the members to be assigned to the struct. You can also have custom inner constructors, but that is often for special purposes, such as for a setup step common to all other constructors: see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-inner-constructor-methods for more.

Thanks for your answer. I think there's been a slight misunderstanding. ExampleStruct should not be constructable from a filename like on the line beginning with ExampleStruct(csvfilename::AbstractString). It should be constructable from the type returned by CSV.File, which I believe is also a CSV.File, as well as other objects which are used to represent other common formats. JSON, parquet, xlsx, ..., etc

Point still holds: use whatever code you usually use to make a DataFrame, then use that code to make the DataFrame member of the ExampleStruct. If you want a CSV.File in the struct instead, then declare ExampleStruct accordingly, without a DataFrame member and with a CSV member if that is what you need. If you want the data member to be any type, then declare it as Any, but you will have to greatly widen/multiply your constructors code accordingly, so that such a situation is better served with an abstract type. That change of topic is better served with another question altogether.

Thanks again for your comments. I think I am missing some understanding of how Julia works - possibly. I want to store a DataFrame type inside the ExampleStruct, but I want to be able to construct it as if it were a DataFrame, in other words by passing a CSV.File to the constructor. This situation is somewhat midway between the two previously discussed options.

It's actually trivial. Now I've learned enough Julia to figure it out, at least.
Just do this:
struct DataFrameWrapper
    df::DataFrame
    function DataFrameWrapper(x)
        new(DataFrame(x))
    end
end

The point here being:

the wrapper type should behave as if it were a DataFrame (same interface)
but it isn't a DataFrame, it just contains one
so the constructor needs to initialize the inner data df using whatever data is passed to it

It's so obvious I actually struggle to explain it a bit.
If I missed something let me know.
methods(DataFrame)

produces a large number of different function calls. It's possible you might need to copy&paste some of them for DataFrameWrapper, but I don't think this is necessary, since calling DataFrame(x) will just dispatch to the correct one. Note x::Any.
